# colors exist or not in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

HI i have one doubt in sql server .
how to find expeted colors exist or not if not exits
then get productid informaton

table : productinfo

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[productInfo](
    [Productid] [int] NULL,
    [Productcolor] [varchar](50) NULL
) 

INSERT [dbo].[productInfo] ([Productid], [Productcolor]) VALUES (1, N'red')
INSERT [dbo].[productInfo] ([Productid], [Productcolor]) VALUES (1, N'blue')
INSERT [dbo].[productInfo] ([Productid], [Productcolor]) VALUES (1, N'white')
INSERT [dbo].[productInfo] ([Productid], [Productcolor]) VALUES (2, N'red')
INSERT [dbo].[productInfo] ([Productid], [Productcolor]) VALUES (2, N'blue')
INSERT [dbo].[productInfo] ([Productid], [Productcolor]) VALUES (3, N'red')
INSERT [dbo].[productInfo] ([Productid], [Productcolor]) VALUES (4, N'red')
INSERT [dbo].[productInfo] ([Productid], [Productcolor]) VALUES (4, N'blue')
INSERT [dbo].[productInfo] ([Productid], [Productcolor]) VALUES (4, N'white')
```

based on above data  I want output like below

```
Productid | Productcolor
2         | white missed
3         | blue missed
3         | white missed
```

each productid should have red,blue,white colors .if any colore not exist then
need to display that productid and color.if all colors exist then no need to display productid

I tried like below

```
select * 
from productinfo 
where Productcolor not in ( 'red','blue','white')
```

could you please tell me how to write a query to achive this task in sql server .

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try the following:

```
SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID,C.Productcolor
FROM
 (
    SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCTID AS PRODUCT_ID FROM DBO.productInfo
 )P
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCTCOLOR 
    FROM DBO.productInfo
)C
 EXCEPT
 SELECT X.PRODUCTID,X.PRODUCTCOLOR
  FROM DBO.productInfo AS X
```

Comment: If the input table has only a single row (`INSERT [dbo].[productInfo] ([Productid], [Productcolor]) VALUES (1, N'red')`), this approach wil not return the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

A possibe approach is to use `EXCEPT` set operator and a `VALUES` table value constructor with all possible colors:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.Productid, v.Productcolor
FROM productInfo p
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('red'), ('blue'), ('white')) v (Productcolor)
EXCEPT
SELECT p.Productid, p.Productcolor
FROM productInfo p
```

Result:

```
Productid   Productcolor
2           white
3           blue
3           white
```

Comment: @user3224208 If you think that this or any other answer is the best solution to your problem, you may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. Only one answer can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a semi anti-join :

```
SELECT T.Productcolor, T.Productid
FROM   productInfo  AS CLP
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT C.Productcolor, P.Productid
                         FROM   productInfo  AS C
                                CROSS JOIN productInfo  AS P) AS T
          ON CLP.Productid = T.Productid AND CLP.Productcolor = T.Productcolor
WHERE  CLP.Productid IS NULL;
```

Some other queries can be written... with a NOT EXISTS :

```
SELECT CP.*
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT C.Productcolor, P.Productid
        FROM   productInfo   AS C
               CROSS JOIN productInfo   AS P) AS CP
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                  FROM   productInfo   AS C
                  WHERE  CP.Productid = C.Productid AND CP.Productcolor = C.Productcolor);
```

Or with a correlated NOT IN :

```
SELECT CP.*
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT C.Productcolor, P.Productid
        FROM   productInfo   AS C
               CROSS JOIN productInfo   AS P) AS CP
WHERE  CP.Productcolor NOT IN(SELECT Productcolor
                             FROM   productInfo AS C
                             WHERE  CP.Productid = C.Productid);
```

Comment: Please, check the result from the execution of this statement, if the input table has only a single row `(INSERT [dbo].[productInfo] ([Productid], [Productcolor]) VALUES (1, N'red'))`.

Comment: It works beacause the colors are extracted from the one an only table...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM productInfo p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROm productInfo pBlue WHERE pBlue.Productcolor='blue' and pBlue.Productid=p.Productid)
  OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROm productInfo pRed WHERE pRed.Productcolor='red' and pRed.Productid=p.Productid)
  OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROm productInfo pWhite WHERE pWhite.Productcolor='white' and pWhite.Productid=p.Productid);
```

It's probably more typing work, but should be faster, when comparing execution plans with other answer given here.